# Analyzing Crash in WinDbg

Tags: c++, .net, windbg

I have a .NET application that is crashing sometimes on exit.  There's a bunch of COM and native stuff underneath the hood, too.  It's a x86 application running on Windows 7 x64.

I've run through some WinDbg tutorials and I *think* I'm executing reasonable steps to get helpful information, but the stack trace itself isn't ringing any bells.

A few other tidbits:

- I can reproduce this pretty consistently, say 75% of the time
- If I clean up the threading (a lot of `Thread.Abort()`), it's reproducible maybe 20% of the time
- Running the same procedure, I've seen a completely different stack trace than the one below, too

I'm using the 32-bit WinDbg.  Here's the general process I've been using:

- open the executable directly from WinDbg
- set symbol path as: `SRV*c:\sym*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`
- type: `.loadby sos clr`
- use the application, and get it to crash

Right after the crash, I get output:

```
(a38.1424): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(a38.1424): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(a38.1fd0): Unknown exception - code c000000d (first chance)
(a38.1fd0): Unknown exception - code c000000d (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=00000000 ebx=004dea1c ecx=7efdd000 edx=00000057 esi=7264d0c0 edi=07f2a248
eip=778715de esp=004dea08 ebp=004def50 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwRaiseException+0x12:
778715de 83c404          add     esp,4
```

If I type in `~` I only get one thread:
`.  0  Id: a38.1fd0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen`

Now, if I type in `!analyze -v` I get a big stack trace:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************
[ a bunch of symbol stuff loading here ]

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!TpReleaseCleanupGroupMembers+276
778e4f52 a1b4009577      mov     eax,dword ptr [ntdll!TppLogpRoutine (779500b4)]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 778e4f52 (ntdll!TpReleaseCleanupGroupMembers+0x00000276)
   ExceptionCode: c000000d
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00001fd0

PROCESS_NAME:  XXXXX.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000000d - An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000000d - An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.

NTGLOBALFLAG:  70

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  004dea6c -- (.cxr 0x4dea6c)
eax=004deee0 ebx=00000001 ecx=7efdd000 edx=00000057 esi=7264d0c0 edi=07f2a248
eip=778e4f52 esp=004deed0 ebp=004def50 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000297
ntdll!TpReleaseCleanupGroupMembers+0x276:
778e4f52 a1b4009577      mov     eax,dword ptr [ntdll!TppLogpRoutine (779500b4)] ds:002b:779500b4=00000000
Resetting default scope

STACK_ADDR_RAW_STACK_SYMBOL: 4deb4c

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[ffffffff]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000 to 77883c04

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

STACK_TEXT:  
778e4f52 ntdll!TpReleaseCleanupGroupMembers+0x276
72630d69 AUDIOSES!DllCanUnloadNow+0x42
7565b5f4 ole32!CClassCache::CDllPathEntry::CanUnload_rl+0x3b
7565b771 ole32!CClassCache::FreeUnused+0x83
7565b68f ole32!CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx+0x36
756a0ccb ole32!CoFreeUnusedLibraries+0x9
15e2f549 GxMetadata+0xf549
15e45e3d GxMetadata!DllCanUnloadNow+0x1686d
77889950 ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x14
7789d6b2 ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess+0x1aa
7789d554 ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x74
754279f4 KERNEL32!ExitProcessStub+0x12
720642f0 mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+0x29c
72064321 mscoreei!CLRRuntimeHostInternalImpl::ShutdownAllRuntimesThenExit+0x15
5ea18580 clr!EEPolicy::ExitProcessViaShim+0x66
5ea1862f clr!SafeExitProcess+0x122
5e9638a9 clr!DisableRuntime+0x120
5e963905 clr!EEPolicy::HandleExitProcess+0x5c
5e9b8af8 clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xdd
5e9b3a30 clr!_CorExeMain+0x4e
720555ab mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x38
72f67f16 MSCOREE!ShellShim__CorExeMain+0x99
72f64de3 MSCOREE!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x8
7542339a KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
77889ef2 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
77889ec5 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
AUDIOSES!DllCanUnloadNow+42
72630d69 ff3514d06472    push    dword ptr [AUDIOSES!_AudioClientThreadpoolCleanupGroup (7264d014)]
```

EDIT 1: (additional info)

!clrstack

```
OS Thread Id: 0x1fd0 (0)
Child SP IP       Call Site
GetFrameContext failed: 1
```

!threads

```
ThreadCount:      7
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 4
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       3
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                   PreEmptive   GC Alloc                Lock
       ID  OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC           Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
   0    1  1fd0 005afe88     16220 Enabled  03051294:03051e6c 00578550     0 STA
XXXX    2   e5c 005801d0      b220 Enabled  0305a22c:0305be6c 00578550     0 MTA (Finalizer)
XXXX    3       00641258     19820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 00578550     0 Ukn
XXXX    4       06e4b800    819820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 00578550     0 Ukn
XXXX    5  18a0 081be620   200b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 00578550     1 MTA
XXXX    8       081d5e18    819820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 00578550     0 Ukn
XXXX    7   158 07ed78d8       220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 00578550     0 Ukn
```

Comment: There are .NET methods in that stack. You might also want to execute `!clrstack` and examine the results - perhaps also post them here.

Comment: `~` command shows unmanaged threads. You may also see managed threads by `!threads` command.

Comment: I added `!clrstack` and `!threads` output

Comment: This could be related to the problem described here as the stack shows a call to TpReleaseCleanupGroupMembers during shutdown http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/27/10298256.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the `ntdll!TpReleaseCleanupGroupMembers` (the same as `kernel32!CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers` - you can look it up on msdn) function (from top of the fault stack) does not like to be called when the process is being shut down - it throws the exception you're seeing (invalid parameter) in this case.

From the presence of two more libs on the stack (**audioses** and **gxmetadata**) I'd guess some objects are destroyed/released way too late. **audioses.dll** seems to the Core Audio API library, not sure about the gxmetadata.dll - can you explain the use of these?

Comment: I have no explanation of these, though it's entirely possible those are  used by some libraries we're using from a third party

Comment: Could this be related to a liberal use of Thread.Abort()?  (I cleaned up a bunch, but not all.  That seemed to reduce the reproducibility, but I can't tell if that's masking the problem or may be fixing it).

Comment: hard to tell at the moment. can you run `lm vm gxmetadata*` in windbg to get the vendor information so it's at least clear what kind of COM objects we're talking about?

Comment: Yes, I see the vendor information -- this is definitely one of the third party DLLs we're using.  What information would be helpful from here?  We're wrapping their COM objects in our own Managed classes.

Comment: On the 2nd thought, abrupt thread termination might be the reason.

Comment: When I swap out that DLL (we have an alternate implementation not dependent on this vendor), I can no longer reproduce the problem, so that library is highly likely related.  I'm not sure the role the thread cleanup is playing though.  Thank you for your help